# How to tell a Nikon or other-brand DX lens from an FX lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

I'm thinking about getting the Nikon D7000 body-only, and want to know how to tell an FX lens from a DX lens. I may upgrade in the future to an FX body and would like to have glass ready to go when I do.

I was looking on the B&H site and can't tell what lenses are FX and what's DX. Any help on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Nikon, it will list with "DX" in the name, otherwise its a FX lens.  For example, on the B&H page, it lists the 35mm DX as "AF-S Nikkor 35mm f/1.8G DX Lens".

For Sigma lenses that work with Nikon, its the "DC" that indicates a DX sized lenses.

For Tamron lenses that work with Nikon, its the "Di II" that indcates a DX sized lenses.

If it doesn't have one of those, its a normal, "FX" sized lenses.

(And realize that FX lenses will work with the D7000, as well as the DX lenses) .

Comment: Hah, we replied at the same time w/the same info, deleting mine :)

Comment: @Shizam: Ya, I saw you replied on the main page and by the time I reloaded - you had deleted.

Answer (score 2):

My site http://lenshero.com (shameless plug) aims to make this easy, for example you can browse [all lenses for Nikon FX](http://lenshero.com/lenses/lens-for-nikon-fx), or [browse lenses for the Nikon D7000](http://lenshero.com/lenses/nikon-d7000-lens).

Answer (score -1):

ps - there is normally quite a price difference as well :-)

most of the FX lens have a better range of appeture as well - so its not a 1-2-1 match. however you can get a 55mm-200mm DX for about $200, the closest to that on the FX is the 70-200 2.8 and thats about $2500...so quite a significant difference.

Comment: ill look into price difference when i know how to distinguish the two sets of lenses. thanks... how much ball park would you say is the gap from DX glass to FX glass?

Comment: well most of the FX lens have a better range of appeture as well - so its not a 1-2-1 match. however you can get a 55mm-200mm DX for about $200, the closest to that on the FX is the 70-200 2.8 and thats about $2500...so quite a significant difference.

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer...

Comment: @Shizam - fair point, I have updated to include the expanded comment